# how to check how many unread message I have in my hotmail account by javamail api?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am Trying to get the unread message number from my hotamil account. I use  but I am having a issue its always return me the all existing email number in inbox. here I share my code:

```
public class testEmail {
    public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
              String password) 

           {
              try {

              //create properties field
              Properties properties = new Properties();
              properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
              properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
             properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");

             // properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");           
              Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
              emailSession.setDebug(false);

              //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
              Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

              store.connect(host, user, password);
              //create the folder object and open it
              Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
              emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

             //for count the unread email 
          FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
          Message messages[] = emailFolder.search(ft);
          System.out.println("No. of Unread Messages : " + messages.length);

              emailFolder.close(false);
              store.close();

              } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (MessagingException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }

           public static void main(String[] args) {

              String host = "pop-mail.outlook.com";// change accordingly
              String mailStoreType = "pop3";
              String username = "abc@hotmail.com";// change accordingly
              String password = "abc";// change accordingly

              check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

           }

        }
```

if i use `FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);`its return 0. is this issue about code or Hotmail account. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the  Folder.getUnreadMessageCount() method.

Comment: I also tried with this method but result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Flags.Flag.SEEN` not working properly in POP3 so I changed it to IMAP. there is another thing if `mail.imap.port = 993` is not working then use 25. the answer is regarding hotmail.

Comment: As described in the document, [POP3 doesn't support any flags due to limitations of the POP3 protocol](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html).